# PyQGIS Close Layout Window

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, layers, export, layouts

I have a script that iterates through layer subgroups in QGIS 3.6, opens a layout with the with the same name as the subgroup and exports a PDF. What I am struggling with is to close the active layout window after the export.
Any ideas or other ways of doing such task?

```
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeGroup, QgsLayerTreeLayer
import os,sys

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
for child in root.children():
    if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
        #print ("- group: " + child.name())
        for subChild in child.children():
            if isinstance (subChild, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                print ("- group: " + child.name() + "-subgroup: " + subChild.name())
                #turn on subgroup
                child.setItemVisibilityChecked(True)
                subChild.setItemVisibilityChecked(True)
                #open layout
                l_out = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(subChild.name())
                iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout=l_out)
                mapName= (subChild.name()+".pdf")
                print (mapName)
                base_path = (r"F:\Documents\PDF")
                print (base_path)
                pdf_path = os.path.join(base_path,mapName)
                print (pdf_path)
                #export layout
                exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(l_out)
                exporter.exportToPdf(pdf_path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
                #close Layout
                ???

                #turn off layer
                subChild.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

Comment: Why do you open the designer in the first place? I think your script will work fine without this step

Comment: You are actually correct, Sir. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one layout open:

```py
designer = iface.openLayoutDesigners()[0]
designer.close()
```

To close a specific layout using its name:

```py
designers = [d for d in iface.openLayoutDesigners() if d.layout().name() == 'Test_Layout']
if designers:
    designers[0].close()
```

Or close all open layouts:

```py
for d in iface.openLayoutDesigners():
    d.close()
```

Comment: This works just fine. Thank you,
It appears the layouts do not have to be open at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [QgsLayoutManager.removeLayout()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutManager.html#a802fa66eca0a46764a794d13a7add551) method to remove layouts:

```
projectLayoutManager.removeLayout(l_out )
```

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. This will do the job. However, using this method the layout is deleted from the project entirely, not just closed.